# $wpdb->replace: WHERE?

Tags: customization, database, query, wpdb, updates

My plan is to **upsert** values in a custom meta table with `$wpdb->replace`.

This is what I try:

```
$up_meta = $wpdb->replace(
    'spieldaten',
    array(
        'spiel_uid' => $uid,
        'dkey' => $prop,
        'dval' => $_POST[$prop]
    )
);
```

What I want to achieve:

- `spiel_uid` and `dkey` is the primary key of my meta table (similar to `wp_postmeta`).
- Update `dval` where `dkey` and `spiel_uid` have the given values
- If there is no such row, just insert the complete record

How can `$wpdb->replace` know `where` I want to replace? `$wpdb->update` in contrast has a `$where` parameter.

Related information:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#REPLACE_row
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows